# How to update serialiazed table field using where condition in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, serialization, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form CFDB7 plugin for storing form data. Plugin saves data in below format.

I want to update this table's "clicked_on_link" column with value "Yes" whose where condition will be submission_id and form_post_id when some condition is met. But I am not understanding how to create the update query. TIA

```
| form_id | form_post_id |form_value     
|      44 |         4561 | a:6:{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:7:"emailid";s:18:"auxxx@gmail.com";s:4:"clicked_on_link";s:2:"No";s:8:"orderNos"s:13:"submission_id";s:2:"39";
|      45 |         7676 | a:3:{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:11:"user_result";s:76:"ScatteredWorkandContent,CommunicationDelays,GettingFeedbackandIdeas,anyOther";
|      46 |         4561 | a:6:{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:7:"emailid";s:18:"auxxx@gmail.com";s:15:"clicked_on_link";s:2:"No";s:13:"submission_id";s:2:"40";
```

Comment: You need to read the value, unserialize it, manipulate the resulting data structure to your liking, and then serialize it again & update the record with that.

Comment: You could write your own data storage and store all of the submitted data using the hook `wpcf7_before_send_mail` to capture and manipulate the data as you wish.

Comment: It would be really helpful if I get to refer some code.

Comment: why not use [Post My CF7 Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/), it allows you to store form submissions using WordPress post and meta fields instead of custom tables and formats.  Makes it much easier to interact with the data using WordPress core functionality.